# Calculating average value of temp from lm-sensors using bash script

Tags: bash, archlinux

As the title says, I am trying to calculate the temperature of a cpu to use it in a conky. The acpi command is strangely not giving me a information about temperature of this laptop... So I am using a lm-sensor.

```
cho:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +54.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +57.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

First, I am not sure what Core 0 and Core 2 represent... I am thinking that they represent each core of my dual core cpu.

Will it be possible to have a one line code that can calculate the average of those temp and get

```
55.5°C
```

as an output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get 56.0°C?

Comment: This should be quite simple to achieve - what have you tried so far and which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: This can be done in single awk as I showed below.

Comment: @Paul R My try is very convoluted which is embarrassing to post here. for i in sensors | tail -n3 | head -n2 | awk '{print $3}'; do echo ${i%.*} | cut -d'+' -f 2; done | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total/2}'... I was trying to find a better solution.

Comment: while your intention to calculate the average temperature over multiple cores is honourable, I think the most relevant result should be the highest temperature, that is, you may want to consider to use a max function rather than an average function. In the hypothetical case of one core overheating, while the others have room temperature, the average would suggests "green" while max correctly gives "red" condition. A chain is as strong as its weakest link, not as strong as the average link strengths.

Comment: @Bushmills Thanks for the information. I think that is very reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe your output with this awk:

```
awk '/^Core /{++r; gsub(/[^[:digit:]]+/, "", $3); s+=$3} END{print s/(10*r) "°C"}'
55.5°C
```

Comment: Thanks! However, dividing 10 at the end gives me 5.55 rather than 55.5.. but besides that it works nicely.

Comment: Since I remove all non-digits so `+54.0°C` becomes `540`. That's the reason I used 10 division. Take it out if you are not getting `.0` in original output.